# Is the expression "moderator's set" used in English? What would you call it?

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests

We are talking about a small suitcase which contains different presentation materials like markers, felt pens, post-its, paper in different shapes, laser pointers etc. for convention organization.

Is the expression *moderator's set* used in English for a set of materials like this? If not, what would it be called?

Comment: I don't know a special word for this. I might call it a _presentation kit_, but that's not a phrase I've ever heard before.

Comment: *Presentation* (or *Moderator's*) *kit* (or *toolkit*) would work, though I don't think it's a standard phrase.  Avoid *set*, which can be grammatically ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm.... These are modern words and so is the list of things in it - laser pointers, post-it tags, etc... However, there are certain terms that you may use which have become widely accepted.

Then again, some of these terms may have specific meanings in certain countries or even age groups.

Eg: Wrench (US) = Adjustable Spanner (UK)

As for your choice of words, I believe you have many alternatives but here are some commonly used terms.

- kit
- case
- presentation kit (as correctly quoted by Colin Fine)
- moderator's case
- pouch
- jacket (also used for CD containers with a zipper)
- moderator's tool kit

Note: This is not the only set of words for it.